# Any performance gotchas when doing mass delete from MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

We are looking at writing log information to a MongoDB logging database but have essentially zero practical experience running Mongo in a production environment.

Every day we'll be writing a million+ log entries. Logs older than (say) a month need to be purged (say) daily. My concern is how Mongo will handle these deletes.

What are the potential issues with this plan with Mongo? 
Do we need to chunk the deletes?
Given we'll be deleting by chronological age (ie: insert order), can I assume fragmentation will not be an issue?
Will the database need to be compacted regularly?

Comment: Using remove to delete one document at a time is certainly less performant than using dropCollection. You can easily test that yourself. Then weigh the costs of re-architecting in order to use dropCollection if the test results warrant it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Potential issues: None, if you can live with eventual consistency.
2. No. A far better approach is to have an [(ISO)Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) field in your documents and set up a [TTL index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/) on it. Assuming the mentioned field holds the time at which the log entry was made, you would setup said index like:

```js
    db.yourCollection.createIndex(
      {"nameOfDateField":1},
      // Seconds in Minutes * Minutes in hour * hours a day * days in month (commercial)
      {"expireAfterSeconds": 2592000}
    )
```

This way, a `mongod` subprocess would take care of deleting the expired data, turning the collection in sort of a round robin database. Less moving parts, less to care about. Please note that the documents will not be deleted the very same second they expire. Under the worst circumstances, it can take up to 2 minutes from their time of expiration (iirc) before they are actually deleted. At median, an expired document should be deleted some 30 seconds after its expiration.

3. Compacting does not reclaim disk space on mmapv1, only on WiredTiger.Keep in mind that documents are **never** fragmented. With the fun fact that the database being compacted will be locked, I have yet to find a proper use case for the compact command. If disk space is your concern: Freed space in the datafiles will be reused. So yes, in a worst case scenario you can have a few additional datafiles allocated. Since I don't know the project's requirements and details, it is you who must decide wether reclaiming a few GB of disk space is worth locking the database for extended periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure MongoDB for **log files rotation** :

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/

You'd certainly be interested by **"Manage journaling"** section too :

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-journaling/

My last suggestion is about **"smallfiles"** option :

Set to false to prevent the overhead of journaling in situations where durability is not required. To reduce the impact of the journaling on disk usage, you can leave journal enabled, and set smallfiles to true to reduce the size of the data and journal files.